# How to call a Function with a RETURN NUMBER

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, sql-navigator

Forgive my lack of knowledge . I'm trying to call an insert function from `sqlnavigator`. I'm able to capture the `prm1.Value`, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to include `RETURN NUMBER` (see SQL below) from my package spec in sqlnavigator. When I run it, nothing is added to ORACLE.

```
 Public Shared Function INSERT_CATEGORY()

    Dim cmdOraCommand As New OracleCommand

    Try
        cmdOraCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdOraCommand.CommandText = "SF_ALEX_TEST.insertCategory"

        Dim prm1 As OracleParameter = cmdOraCommand.Parameters.Add( _ 
            "inCategory", OracleType.VarChar)
        prm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        prm1.Value = strCategory

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    Finally
        cmdOraCommand.Dispose()
    End Try

End Function
```

SQL/ORACLE

```
FUNCTION insertCategory(inCategory IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER

IS
    vReturnedValue NUMBER;
    vID NUMBER;
    vExist NUMBER;
BEGIN
    IF inCategory IS NULL THEN

        vReturnedValue := 0;
        RETURN vReturnedValue;
    ELSE

        BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT(MNT_CATEGORY) INTO vExist
            FROM MNT_CATEGORIES
            WHERE MNT_CATEGORIES.MNT_CATEGORY = upper(inCategory);
        END;

        IF vExist = 0 THEN
            BEGIN
                SELECT SEQ_MNT_LOG.NEXTVAL INTO vID FROM DUAL;

                INSERT INTO MNT_CATEGORIES(MNT_CATEGORY_ID, MNT_CATEGORY)
                VALUES (vID, UPPER(inCategory));
                COMMIT;

                vReturnedValue := vID;
                RETURN vReturnedValue;

                EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    vReturnedValue := SQLCODE;
                    RETURN vReturnedValue;
            END;

        ELSE

            vReturnedValue := vExist * -1;
            RETURN vReturnedValue;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the command but not opening a connection or executing the command.
You're also creating a parameter but not adding it to the command.
You will also need another parameter with `ParameterDirection.Return` if you want to capture the return value. You cannot check the value of that parameter until the reader is closed.

[Here are the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Scott, thanks for the answer. I opened a connection and executed the command. Additionally I used `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I corrected my VB.net code to properly communicate with Oracle/sqlnavigator.

Thanks @Scott Hannen

```
Public Shared Function INSERT_CATEGORY() As Boolean

    Dim cmdMntID As New OracleCommand
    cmdMntID.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmdMntID.CommandText = "SF_ALEX_TEST.insertCategory"

    Dim prm1 As OracleParameter = cmdMntID.Parameters.Add("inCategory", OracleType.VarChar)
    prm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    prm1.Value = strCategory

    cmdMntID.Parameters.Add("vID", OracleType.Number).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

    cmdMntID.Connection = ORA_CON

    cmdMntID.ExecuteNonQuery()

    vID = cmdMntID.Parameters("vID").Value

    If cmdMntID.Parameters("vID").Value > 1 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: If it worked don't forget to mark it as answered. Thanks